# AWS EC2 User Data: Commands not recognized when using sudo

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to create an EC2 User-data script to run other scripts on boot up. However, the scripts that I run fail to recognize some commands and variables that I'd already declared. I'm running the commands as the "ubuntu" user but it still isn't working.

My user-data script looks something like this:

```
export user="ubuntu"
sudo su $user -c ". ./run_script"
```

Within the script, I have these lines:

```
THIS_PATH="/some/path"
echo "export SOME_PATH=$THIS_PATH" >> ~/.bashrc

source ~/.bashrc
```

However, the script can't run `SOME_PATH/application`, and `echo $SOME_PATH` this returns a blank line. I'm confused because `$SOME_PATH/application` works when I log into the EC2 using SSH and my debug logs using `whoami` returns "ubuntu."

Am I missing something here?

Comment: User Data scripts run as the `root` user. Try simply creating the files without using `sudo`, but you will need to `chown` the files to the desired user so they can access them.

Comment: Is the user ubuntu already created when you call `sudo` ? Try `sudo su ubuntu -c "touch /tmp/sudo_test"` and look who created that file. Look at the modification date of `find / -name .bashrc` which one is changed (from root? Does this change after `sudo su - $user ...`?)

Comment: To John: I can create files using both the root and ubuntu user.
To Walter: Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem. It seems that source ~/.bashrc isn't enough to restart the shell -- the environment variables worked after I referenced them in another bash script.

Answer (score 0):

Your data script is executed as root and su command leaves $HOME and other ENV variables intact (note that sudo is redundant). "su -" does not help either

So, do not use ~ or $HOME but full path   /home/ubuntu/.bashrc

Comment: I don't think this is a path error. I've tried your solution and it doesn't work.